# Receiving Invalid Qualifier error when attempting to access a form and subform using variable names?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying perform a `RecordsetClone` but I keep getting a

> **Invalid Qualifier**

compile error.

Currently I have a form, and within it I have a subform that contains a `Datasheet`. I created a function to pass in the name of the form as well as name of the subform:

```
Public Sub testModel(nameOfForm As String, nameOfSubform As String)
    Dim myForm As Access.Form
    Dim mySubForm As Access.SubForm

    If formIsOpen(nameOfForm) = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm nameOfForm, acNormal
    End If

    Set myForm = Forms(nameOfForm)
    Set mySubForm = myForm.Controls(nameOfSubform )

    With Forms!myForm.name.mySubForm.name.Form.RecordsetClone
       ...
    End With

End Sub
```

The reason for using a variable for the form and subform is because different forms and subforms will be using this function.

The error is definitely involved with the syntax `Forms!myForm.name.mySubForm .name.Form.RecordsetClone`, and I'm pretty confident it is incorrect.

I've also tried:

```
Forms!myForm.name.mySubForm.Form.RecordsetClone
```

If I replaced it, directly using the name of the form and subform name, there is no issue, i.e.:

```
Forms!frmParentForm.frmChildSubForm.Form.RecordsetClone
```

I have printed out the name of `myForm` and `mySubForm` via its `.name` property and it appears to display the correct name for each.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how exactly I can use variable names in place of the actual names of my form and subform? What should the correct syntax be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove those `.name` things. They're not supposed to be there:

```
With Forms!myForm.mySubForm.Form.RecordsetClone
   ...
End With
```

If you're going to use that declared subform variable, it's even more simple:

```
With mySubForm.Form.RecordsetClone
    ...
End With
```